# Different reporting frequency for different types of metrics in micrometer

Tags: micrometer, spring-micrometer

Can I set different reporting frequency for different types of metrics in micrometer? For example I want send endpoints metrics with 10s step and the others with 5s step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a property for reporting frequency per meter registry but AFAICT, there's no concept for reporting frequency per meter. If you'd like to pursue this, you can create an issue to request the feature in its issue tracker: https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/issues

Comment: Thank you! I will create an issue. I think that It would be useful.